# Automate creation of Composer command for upgrading TYPO3 to next major version

Tags: composer-php, typo3

Currently in the process of upgrading a TYPO3 site with TYPO3 v9 **Composer** to next major release 10.4.

How do I automate the process - instead of manually putting together the composer command where I have to check each extension and find out which version I need to upgrade to, is there a way to do this automatically or assist in creating the `composer require` command with all system and third party extensions?

e.g. as result I would like to perform this (or the equivalent of this):

```
composer require typo3/cms-backend:10.4 typo3/cms-core:10.4  ...(all system extension) \
... helhum/typo3-console:^6.0.0 ... (3rdparty extensions with correct version constraint) \
--update-with-dependencies
```

Comment: In my opinion it's a waste of time. TYPO3 uses rules of [semantic versioning](https://semver.org/), which means, that major updates can bring changes, that are **not** backward compatible, both in extensions and source. For an example all methods are marked as depreciated on major updates, also many extensions which weren't updated since some time will have marked dependency joined with previous major upd. In other words each major update requires detailed analysis, especially if this instance was already updated from earlier versions like `8.x`, `6.x`, `4.x` etc.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by waste of time. I always spend considerable time with testing and adapting on a test system before the update is done on production. By this time, I have already fixed the deprecations on our extensions and done testing on a clone of our system under v10. However this is done without Composer. I have about 50 extensions - besides the system extensions. Creating the composer version constraints for this is a tedious task and I was hoping to speed this up. Already did several major upgrades before, but not with Composer.

Comment: I just mean, that making major updates almost always you'll need to check and/or fix *manually* older extensions. Everything depends on each scenario and from my experience i would say that creating automatization for this fits in range from difficult to impossible. Each instation may be very different so IMHO it's better to invest time in *good practices* about updates than trying to create auto-solution.

Comment: To clarify: I did not intend to automate the update without checking the extensions. My intention was simply to automate part of the update, namely the creation of the composer require command. I will update the question to make this more clear. I have already used the extension scanner, am fixing deprecations and am working on a test system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Automating the update is a good idea since it lowers the needed time for backend lock/content freeze for the relaunch.

My steps for the **final relaunch** are:

- make sure no data gets changed: lock the backend, disable any frontend forms that would change data.
- fetch/sync live data into your local test system
- run update script
- upload/sync updated data to some temporary place on the live system
- temporarily disable live website
- move data on the live system into the right places/import DB (you can even prepare that by using a different database and a symlink to your data)
- re-enable website, remove backend lock

In order for that to work, you just need a script that allows you to repeat the update process locally (or as a CI pipeline) as often as you need to until you are satisfied with reproducible results.

I know there are some helper scripts/extensions around to facilitate that but I prefer to just put it together as shell scripts. Locally I will have the newest code and what we prepare now is a script that integrates new code with old data (with "data" I refer to DB & /fileadmin, /uploads).

So here are just some pointers:

- If you use ddev, there will be a `ddev pull` command in the upcoming v1.17 that facilitates fetching live data. Until now, I used this [custom command for ddev](https://github.com/drud/ddev-contrib/tree/master/custom-commands/dump-and-deploy-db).
- The commands in the `vendor/bin/typo3 cleanup:` namespace can make it less likely that you are dealing with an inconsistent database
- Custom Upgrade Wizards are great for anything where you want to use TYPO3 API. - you can run them with `vendor/bin/typo3cms upgrade:wizard`
- typo3-console gives you easy raw SQL access to the database (saves you from creating an upgrade wizard for trivial DB queries): For example `vendor/bin/typo3cms database:import <<< "UPDATE tt_content SET hidden=1 WHERE ..."`
- DB compare is `vendor/bin/typo3cms database:updateschema`

For your questions:

> do I perform the update of core and 3rdparty extensions in one scoop or is it safer to deactivate the (some?) 3rdparty extensions

Some Upgrade Wizards might behave differently if certain extensions are installed. This is especially true for TCA-reliant migrations. So I would recommend to update all extensions in one step.

> Also, how do I automate the process (composer command)

The way I do it you will have to run that composer command only once and afterwards you commit the `composer.lock`. Building it can be a little hassle but I do not see a need for automating it.

Answer (score 1):

When I wrote the question, I did not realize, [typo3-rector](https://github.com/sabbelasichon/typo3-rector) already has a solution built-in. With rector, you can automatically get the extension versions updated in your composer.json when you switch to the next major release.

See the official documentation for typo3/rector for up-to-date instructions:

- https://github.com/sabbelasichon/typo3-rector/blob/main/docs/best_practice_guide.md#composer-packages-update

**Important**: This will not give you a warning when an extension is not available for the next release (you will get that when you try `composer update`). As always you should work with a version control system and not commit your changes until ready. Work on a development system, not on production.

---

You can use rector/rector to check and fix your PHP files, but also, for example composer.json.

For example do this to test:

```
composer require typo3/cms-core:^10.4.0
composer require dmind/cookieman:^2.9.2
composer require georgringer/news
composer require rector/rector --dev
```

(I used this extension cookieman for this example, because the latest versions only support one TYPO3 version each - though the versioning is a bit weird. I use "news" because it is currently not available for v11).

Create a `rector.php` with

```
vendor/bin/rector init --template-type=typo3
```

Add / comment out checks for `composer.json` for TYPO3 10:

rector.php:

```
$containerConfigurator->import(Typo3SetList::COMPOSER_PACKAGES_104_CORE);
$containerConfigurator->import(Typo3SetList::COMPOSER_PACKAGES_104_EXTENSIONS);
```

Now apply rector (to composer.json only):

```
vendor/bin/rector process  --clear-cache composer.json
```

switch to 11:

rector.php:

```
$containerConfigurator->import(Typo3SetList::COMPOSER_PACKAGES_110_CORE);
$containerConfigurator->import(Typo3SetList::COMPOSER_PACKAGES_110_EXTENSIONS);
```

Now apply rector (to `composer.json` again):

```
vendor/bin/rector process  --clear-cache composer.json
```

The requirements not only for cms-core, but also for the extension should have changed.

Now continue with `composer update` or whatever you usually use to update the `composer.lock` when `composer.json` is changed directly.